# MongoDB PHP driver installation issue in Red Hat Linux

Tags: php, redhat-enterprise-linux, mongodb

My server OS is Red Hat Linux. I installed MongoDB 2.2.3 successfully on my server, following [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux). I also tried following [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php) for installing the PHP driver for MongoDB, but when I execute the `sudo pecl install mongo` command, I get the following errors:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
downloading mongo-1.3.7.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.3.7.tgz (126,064 bytes)
............................done: 126,064 bytes
49 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7
running: /var/tmp/mongo/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable Mongo extension... yes, shared
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands &quot;+=&quot;... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/libtool --mode=compile cc -I./util -I. -I/var/tmp/mongo -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/main -I/var/tmp/mongo -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/util -I/var/tmp/mongo/util -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/mcon -I/var/tmp/mongo/mcon  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/mongo/php_mongo.c -o php_mongo.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I./util -I. -I/var/tmp/mongo -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/main -I/var/tmp/mongo -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/util -I/var/tmp/mongo/util -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rooto4WFLx/mongo-1.3.7/mcon -I/var/tmp/mongo/mcon -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/mongo/php_mongo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_mongo.o
In file included from /usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39,
from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:242,
from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
from /var/tmp/mongo/php_mongo.c:20:
/usr/include/linux/limits.h:5: error: expected identifier or â(â before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:755,
from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
from /var/tmp/mongo/php_mongo.c:20:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h: In function âis_numeric_stringâ:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:201: error: âlong_min_digitsâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:201: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:201: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it? MongoDB itself is running successfully.

My PEAR, PHP and Zend versions are:

- PEAR Version: 1.9.4
- PHP Version: 5.3.3
- Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0